# I have HP dv7 laptop. intel core i5 2.53 and 6GB of RAM

Tags: memory

I have HP dv7 laptop. Intel core i5 2.53 and 6GB of RAM. but now it is showing 6GB RAM (2.43GB Usable) I Checked both of RAMs separately. on of them that is 4GB it is showing 2.43 GB usable. an second one is showing 2GB (1.86GB Usable). but when I am inserting both of them, again it is showing 2.43GB usable. when it has original windows 7 home premium, it was like this. the computer was working too slowly. it was like that. but when I changed from win 7 home prem. 64bit to win 8 professional 32bit, again it is showing like that.

Answer (score 1):

The 32-bit version of Windows has limits imposed on memory by Microsoft, usually 4GB on a desktop. To get around this, you will either have to use PAE or switch to a 64-bit version of the OS. I would not recommend the former, as PAE tends to have a slight performance hit, and it will require some sort of advanced hack.

According to [this page](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/R-and-L-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/4gb-ram-installed-but-only-2-43gb-usable/td-p/244998), the 32-bit version of Windows 8 can only USE up to 3GB of RAM. The reason that you are not being able to use all 3 GB's is because the integrated graphics controller takes up a certain amount of RAM, which becomes unusable for anything other than the graphics controller.

> Intel graphics do not have dedicated memory but utilizes some of the
>   computer's system memory. The amount of memory used for graphics may
>   be a fixed amount or may vary up to a maximum amount. It depends on if
>   the computer manufacturer has configured the computer to use a fixed
>   amount, a dynamic amount (varying up to a maximum amount), or a
>   combination of both fixed and dynamic amounts of graphics memory.

According to the [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01758220.pdf) for the dv6:

> Intel Extreme Graphics - Intel GMA 4700MHD - Up to 1759 MB of graphics
>   subsystem memory on computer models equipped with 4096 MB of main
>   system memory (64-bit OS)

Comment: The first sentence is true if you refer only to desktop versions of Windows; the second sentence is false. 32-bit operating systems are perfectly capable of addressing more than 4 GiB of RAM using [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), just like 8-bit operating systems are capable of addressing more than 256 bytes of memory. Windows 8's memory limit is artificially imposed my Microsoft.

Comment: @Dennis I know that PAE allows for more memory for 32-bit systems, however I thought Microsoft imposed a limit on the memory.

Comment: @Dennis Thus per the question, there is no way for a Microsoft user to use PAE to extend the memory beyond microsoft's limitation.

Comment: I don't disagree with your conclusion. I was just talking about the *wording* of the first paragraph. 1. Windows Server 2000 Advanced 32-bit can address 8 GiB of memory. 2. There are ways around the limit in Vista and 7 ([source](http://www.evga.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=960087&mpage=1)), although I haven't – and wouldn't – try them out myself.

Comment: @Dennis Alright, I'll edit it